# How do I play the Euro 12 expansion in FIFA '12?

Tags: origin, fifa-12

I bought the Euro 2012 expansion pack for FIFA 12 in the Origin store, and I can't figure out how to play it. I went into the "UEFA Euro 2012" menu option, but all I got was a screen saying "Purchase Euro 2012 Video Game".

**EDIT**
Here's what the EA help site gave me:
[image]
It doesn't even have an option for FIFA 12.
I've already bought it, why can't I play it?

Comment: old question, but did you buy FIFA 12 also?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Fifa 12? You need it to run the expansion.

Assuming you DO have Fifa 12, did you had it installed before downloading UEFA EURO 2012? According to [this](https://www.ea.com/en-gb/news/euro-faq-us-2):

> Note: User must already have FIFA 12 installed before they begin the installation of UEFA EURO 2012™.

Comment: I downloaded and installed FIFA 12 from Origin, and it then automatically downloaded Euro 12 after that.

Comment: Have you tried contacting origin support? Their support is way better than steam, for either solving a problem or at least for response time.

Comment: See edited question.